# Syntax error on update SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I'm getting a syntax error when I want to use md5 over url column. Not sure what's wrong with it:

```
update table {$GLOBALS['tables']['tableame']} set urlhash = md5(url)
```

Error message:

> Database error 1064 while doing query You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table tablename set urlhash = md5(url)' at line 1

Comment: Can you post error as well to help you better

Comment: What error do you actually get? What is the value of `$GLOBALS['tables']['tableame']`?

Comment: Database error 1064 while doing query You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table tablename set urlhash = md5(url)' at line 1

Comment: @JohnConde $GLOBALS['tables']['tablename'] is the table

Comment: `update {$GLOBALS['tables']['tableame']} set urlhash = md5(url)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try passing md5 in single quotes as that is a string

```
update {$GLOBALS['tables']['tableame']} set urlhash = 'MD5_URL_HERE'
```

following is the syntax

UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = `new_value' [WHERE condition];

Comment: Now you have a literal `md5(url)` as your value

Comment: @JohnConde what ever update query executes properly without errors

Comment: @PraveenGovind  tried that but still have the error.

Comment: There may not be an error but they get the wrong value. And now your updated answer also causes a problem because it doesn't actually perform the MD5 hash in the query like the OP requires. Plus it doesn't address the syntax error.

Comment: @xh3n1 updated my answer check your query you don't need update table {tablename} it should be update {tablename}

Comment: @JohnConde Thank you for clarification, I will be more specific when answering next time. Cheers.